# Validating string against predefined formats in JavaScript (postal codes)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, country-codes

Not sure how easy this would be, but maybe some of you guys can help.

I have a file that contains acceptable formats for postal codes in different countries.

Example below is for United States, it's listed like so:

```
    COUNTRY CODE |     FORMAT    | # OF CHARS TO VALIDATE
     US          |   99999-9999  | 5 |
     US          |   999999999   | 5 |
     US          |   99999       | 5 |
```

*(Note: I added a header and extra spaces to make it more read-able).*

It gets more complex for countries such as UK which uses ALPHA NUMERIC postal codes as shown below:

```
    COUNTRY CODE |     FORMAT    | # OF CHARS TO VALIDATE
    GB           |     A9 9AA    | 4 |
    GB           |     AA9A9AA   | 5 |
    GB           |     AA9A 9AA  | 6 |
    GB           |     AA99AA    | 4 |
    GB           |     AA999AA   | 5 |
    GB           |     AA99 9AA  | 6 |
    GB           |     AA9 9AA   | 5 |
    GB           |     A9A9AA    | 4 |
    GB           |     A9A 9AA   | 5 |
    GB           |     A99AA     | 3 |
    GB           |     A999AA    | 4 |
    GB           |     A99 9AA   | 5 |
```

So basically what I need to do is take a postal code that is entered from a USER and validate this against my accepted formats for that country.

I honestly have no idea how to go about doing this and was wondering if it is even possible with JavaScript.

Any suggestions, thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I figure I would need to put all of the available formats in an array and validate that way. Just not sure if JS can even validate like that without using a regexp. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use regex, it will be the most efficient way. If you put all available formats in an array and check against those as you suggested in the comment then you will run across problems because it will check for length and not the chars pattern within.

You could always put a list of all postal codes and check against those in JS without using regex but that is worse than it sounds. Ok to use to check a few items, very bad idea for postal codes.

Regex is your friend for this task.